# How to convert pdf files in multiple folders into multiple pdf files matching the folder names

Tags: pdf, script, batch-file

I have multiple folders, each one containing multiple pdf image files like this:

```
  Folder 1 
     file1.pdf
     file2.pdf
     file3.pdf
     ...
     file100.pdf
  Folder 2 
     file1.pdf
     file2.pdf
     file3.pdf
     ...
     file100.pdf
  Folder 3 
     file1.pdf
     file2.pdf
     file3.pdf
     ...
     file100.pdf
  ...
  Folder 94
     file1.pdf
     file2.pdf
     file3.pdf
     ...
     file100.pdf
```

Is there any way to create a sort of script that outputs at one time each folder as one pdf file like this :

```
Folder1.pdf
Folder2.pdf
Folder3.pdf
...
Folder94.pdf
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Merge PDF Files in a Folder to One PDF File Matching the Folder Name

Since you have a solution to convert all the JPG files into PDF files, you need a solution that will merge all PDF files in a folder to a single PDF file merged chronologically based on file names.

You can use [PDFtk Free](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) and its  **CLI PDFtk** with the `cat` parameter in a batch script to automate the operations to convert all PDF files within a folder to a single PDF with the folder name as the file name.

> "PDFtk Free is our friendly graphical tool for quickly merging and
>    splitting PDF documents and pages. It is free to use for as long as
>    you like."
>
> "Power Users: PDFtk Free comes with our command-line tool, PDFtk
>   Server. So you get both the GUI and the command-line interface to PDFtk!"

---

### Batch Script

> **Note:** The `SourceParentDir=` value will be the full path to the location where the subfolders with the PDF files reside which you need
>   to merge.

```
@ECHO OFF

SET "SourceParentDir=C:\Root\Parent\Folder"
FOR /R "%SourceParentDir%" %%A IN (.) DO (
    IF /I NOT [%%~A]==[%SourceParentDir%\.] pdftk "%SourceParentDir%\%%~NA\*.pdf" cat output "%SourceParentDir%\%%~NA.pdf"
    )
PAUSE
EXIT
```

---

### Batch Script (Inverse Order)

```
@ECHO OFF

SET "SourceParentDir=C:\Root\Parent\Folder"
FOR /R "%SourceParentDir%" %%A IN (.) DO (
    IF /I NOT [%%~A]==[%SourceParentDir%\.] pdftk "%SourceParentDir%\%%~NA\*.pdf" cat output "%SourceParentDir%\temp.pdf"
    IF EXIST "%SourceParentDir%\temp.pdf" pdftk "%SourceParentDir%\temp.pdf" cat end-1 output "%SourceParentDir%\%%~NA.pdf"
    IF EXIST "%SourceParentDir%\%%~NA.pdf" IF EXIST "%SourceParentDir%\temp.pdf" DEL /Q /F "%SourceParentDir%\temp.pdf"
    )
PAUSE
EXIT
```

---

### Further Resources

- [FOR /R](https://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html)

  > ```
  > FOR /R [[drive:]path] %variable IN (set) DO command [command-parameters]
  >
  >     Walks the directory tree rooted at [drive:]path, executing the FOR
  >     statement in each directory of the tree.  If no directory
  >     specification is specified after /R then the current directory is
  >     assumed.  If set is just a single period (.) character then it
  >     will just enumerate the directory tree.
  > ```
- [IF](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)
- **Batch Substitutions (FOR /?)**

  > In addition, substitution of FOR variable references has been
  >   enhanced. You can now use the following optional syntax:
  >
  > ```
  > %~nI        - expands %I to a file name only
  > ```
- **`pdftk.exe --Help`**

  > ```
  >       cat [<page ranges>]
  >              Assembles (catenates) pages from input PDFs to create a new
  >              PDF. Use cat to merge PDF pages or to split PDF pages from
  >              documents. You can also use it to rotate PDF pages. Page
  >              order in the new PDF is specified by the order of the given
  >              page ranges. Page ranges are described like this:
  >
  >              <input PDF handle>[<begin page number>[-<end page num-
  >              ber>[<qualifier>]]][<page rotation>]
  > ```